# What is the MIPS equivalent on these pseudoinstructions?

Tags: mips, computer-science

1. `rol  $t7, $t6, $t8`

   This is like:

   ```
   sll $t0, $t3, 8 # get rid of bits 31-23
   srl $t1, $t3, 24 #move 31-32 to 7-0
   or $t7, $t0, $t1 # do an or statement
   ```

   right?
2. What about this one:

   ```
   ld   $t2, 0($t8)
   ```